# Can reports be automatically generated on a scheduled basis using TFS data?

Tags: tfs, automation, report

The current situation: We're manually putting together a weekly report using the information available to us in TFS.  It's a mind-numbing process that takes each scrum master several hours a week to piece together.  The reports include information on sprint progress, blocked stories/features, workload per team, etc.

My question: Is there a way of automating this process to run on a weekly basis and export the results to an Excel file?  TFS data must be housed in a database somewhere, but I'm not sure how restricted access to this database is.

Answer (score 0):

After you create and publish reports, you can use Report Manager to view, organize, and configure those reports. This could be achieved by using **Report Manager**. Take a look at this tutorial: [View, organize, and configure reports using Report Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/view-upload-organize-reporting-services-reports?view=tfs-2018)

> After you create and publish reports in SQL Server Report Designer,
>   you can use SQL Server Reporting Services' Report Manager to view,
>   organize, and configure those reports. By using Report Manager, you
>   can group related reports in folders, adjust parameters and data
>   sources, and **schedule automated reports**.
>
> You can also configure different methods by which your reports are
>   saved. For example, you can save a copy of a report (sometimes
>   referred to as a snapshot) as report history. You can also export and
>   save reports and have reports copied automatically to a file share.

If you want to import report to Excel, you could write a small PowerShell script using Rest API to query info  such as related work items, then you add a scheduled job that'll execute that script .